# How to convert negative value into zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
    SELECT  name ,
        ( SUM(CASE WHEN TransTypeName LIKE 'credit%' THEN amount
                   ELSE 0
              END) - SUM(CASE WHEN TransTypeName LIKE 'Debit%' THEN amount
                              ELSE 0
                         END) ) * 5 / 100 AS Interest
    FROM .....
```

This query return some negative value,I want convert negative value into zero.
How to write a query

Comment: erm, negative values are negative....why would a debit(credit) be zero?

Comment: Hi Mitch,I understand your question,But this is my requirement  task.

Comment: related content: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187090/does-sql-server-support-greatest-and-least-if-not-what-is-the-common-workaround

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
SELECT t1.name AS Name, CASE WHEN t1.Interest > 0 THEN Interest ELSE 0 END AS Interest
FROM (select name, (sum(case when TransTypeName like 'credit%' then amount else 0 end) - sum(case when TransTypeName like 'Debit%' then amount else 0 end)) *5/100 as Interest from ...........) as t1
```

Answer (score 5):

Just give this

```
select greatest(:yourval,0)
```

(Works in Azure and SQL Server 2022.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

For those who prefer one short line instead of long CASE statements.

Use `isnull(nullif(sign({column name}),-1),0)` :

```
select isnull(nullif(sign(-100),-1),0) as negative
select isnull(nullif(sign(0),-1),0) as zero
select isnull(nullif(sign(100),-1),0) as positive
```

Answer (score 3):

use a second case statement:

```
select name, (sum(case when TransTypeName like 'credit%' then (case when amount>0 then amount else 0 end;) else 0 end) -
sum(case when TransTypeName like 'Debit%' then (case when amount>0 then amount else 0 end;) else 0 end)) *5/100 as Interest
from ...........
```

if you do not what to return a sum which is negativ:

```
select name, (case when (sum(case when TransTypeName like 'credit%' then amount else 0 end) -
sum(case when TransTypeName like 'Debit%' then amount ) else 0 end)) *5/100)<0 then 0 else  (sum(case when TransTypeName like 'credit%' then amount else 0 end) -
sum(case when TransTypeName like 'Debit%' then amount ) else 0 end)) *5/100) as Interest
from ...........
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.name AS Name, CASE WHEN t1.Interest > 0 THEN Interest ELSE 0 END AS Interest
FROM (select name, (sum(case when TransTypeName like 'credit%' then amount else 0 end) - sum(case when TransTypeName like 'Debit%' then amount else 0 end)) *5/100 as Interest from ...........) as t1
```